# Target iframe body and remove nodeType 3 (=text)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to access an iframe's content but for some reason it doesn't work. I can do this which will work:

```
$('iframe').load(function (){

$('#iframeID').contents().find('SOMETHING').remove();

});
```

Anything else does work except for this code:

```
$('iframe').load(function (){

$('#iframeID').contents().find('body *:not(.ThisClass *)').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();

});
```

It should work but it doesn't. What could be the problem? There are no errors in my console.

Comment: My guess would be `'body *:not(.ThisClass *)'` can that be simplified any?

Comment: @Kevin B No, this is the most basic thing I could do, anything else wouldn't work in my project (so I have experienced..) Let me know if you know how to simplify

Comment: Right, but what you're currently doing also isn't working in your project, it must be not selecting any elements. Break apart the selector and test it piece by piece, first with `body *`

Comment: @Kevin B The code works good on the same page, meaning if I don't refer to the Iframe. It's only when I try to access Iframe I add this part to the code:  `$('#iframeID').contents().find ` I don't see anything wrong with this...

Comment: It's not working, so it must be wrong. Figure out where it fails. try `body *`, if that gives you what you expect it to, add on the `:not(.ThisClass)`, and then finally add on the last `*`.

Comment: So just to be clear this works good on document: `$('body *:not(.ThisClass *)').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).remove();`

Comment: I'm trying to help you figure out why it isn't working. Just looking at a full selector and seeing it return 0 results doesn't get us anywhere other than being able to say it doesn't work.

Comment: this works for me `$('#iframeID').contents().find("body").contents().filter(function() {`

Comment: @Kevin B Thanks for the comment +1 :) I did what you suggested and it seems it only doesn't work when I add this `*` to the class like so `not(.ThisClass *)` It works when I remove it but it doesn't get me what I want. What are my options to select everything inside `.ThisClass` ?

Comment: to select everything that is not a descendent of `.ThisClass`?

Comment: I think descendent has to do with complete elements. So text which is just outside the element wouldn't get selected if I target only the descendent (I think...)

Comment: well, jQuery doesn't select text other than with .contents, so ignore the fact that text exists when using selectors. If you want text, you'll have to target that text's parent node and use .contents().

Comment: The selector you were using previously suggested that you wanted all elements that were not a descendant of an element that had the class `ThatClass`, you then got the contents of all of those elements and filtered down to only text nodes.

Comment: @Kevin B Yes exactly, leaving only the text nodes of `ThatClass` Im still confused on what my options are besides `*`...

Comment: Try moving the `:not` to `.not` `.find('body *').not('.ThisClass *').contents...`

Comment: Ok I think I understand...So instead of using the all selector I should use contents() for my class, right?

Comment: I was still typing when you offered the answer:) THANK YOU very much. If you put it as answer I will accept.